# For what values of x is the series convergent: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n / (n + |x|)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Have tried doing the root test to no avail as I get a $n^{1/n}$ term. Ratio test not helpful either. Could look at absolute convergence but then get stuck on showing how $1/(n+x)$ converges and specifically for which values of $x$.

Comment: The root test will fail. It is an alternating series.

Comment: Have you tried comparing it with the series without $|x|$? Or maybe Leibniz test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown we meet again..

Answer (score 2):

It's convergent for all $x$ (even complex), since $1/(n+|x|)$ is decreasing and the series is alternating.

Comment: By the alternating test right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** use this for partial sums:$$0<\frac{(-1)^{2k}}{2k +|x|}+\frac{(-1)^{2k+1}}{2k +1+ |x|}=\frac{1}{(2k+|x|)(2k+1+|x|)}<\frac{1}{(2k)^2}$$